# Excel lookup multiple columns, find the latest date and return corresponding value from another column

Tags: excel-formula

I need to lookup 2 columns (column A, column AA), find the latest date from say column S (there may be multiple rows) and return the corresponding value from column AD. So, basically I need the latest entry from column AD.

I've already tried few suggestions found online with no luck. Tried using a helper column to pull the max date and then use this to lookup but my excel crashed after calculating for 10 minutes. This happened repetitively.

Few things to note: The source file contains around 20,000 rows and the file where I have the formulas contains 24  columns with this same formula. I'd appreciate if you can assist me with a formula that works somewhat faster.